# Facebook TestConsole

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can anybody tell me how I can put an Array into the testconsole for example here?
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/dashboard.multiAddNews/

the "uids" and "news" requests an array parameter. It´s really funny right now for me, because i tried many methods and i was searching around. i didnt find one example of what i can put in there...

I was trying some of these

```
{"message":"test"}
"message":"test"
[{"message":"test"}]
[{\"message\":\"test\"]
message=test;
```

Comment: BTW this method is deprecated, actually all dashbord namespace methods are deprecated.

Comment: i know this, cause i can read

Comment: im talking about the test console. and the link is just an example

Answer (score 0):

Please note:
1) the above method is deprecated
2) it won't work in any case in the test console since it should be called with app access token and the test console is working with user token.

To your question: uids should look like ["12345","56789"], while news is array of jsons

hope this helps

Comment: no this helps not, I asked espacally for news, because there must be name value pairs, which your example does not provide. look at my example, there is more then you provide. 2) it HAVE to work with test console, it just translate the value into querystring, and this must be possible to write thorugh console. has nothing to do with tokens. the error message just says, news must be an array.

Comment: [{"message":"test"}] for news and ["12345","56789"] for uids, however you will need and app access token.

Comment: as you can see, i tried this one and it still says, news must be an array